# Static var in protocol and reflection

Tags: ios, swift, reflection

Doing basic reflection in Swift, I encountered a couple of road blocks. The first has to do with static var in a protocol. Isn't it the same as requesting the implementation to define a class var? The second has to do with returning the name of the class when it's passed as type AnyClass? Is this the right thing to do?

```
protocol Nameable {
    static var name: String { get }
}

func nameForClass(cls: AnyClass) -> String {
    var name = ""
    if let cls = cls as? Nameable {
        name = cls.name
    }
    if (name.isEmpty) {
        name = NSStringFromClass(cls.self)
    }
    return name
}

class A : Nameable {
    static var name: String {
        return "ClassA"
    }
}

class B : Nameable {
    static var name: String {
        return ""
    }
}


println(nameForClass(A.self)) // Should print "ClassA"
println(nameForClass(B.self)) // Should print "B"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd use overloading in this situation:

```
func nameForClass<T>(Type: T.Type) -> String {
    return "\(Type)"
}

func nameForClass<T: Nameable>(Type: T.Type) -> String {
    return Type.name.isEmpty ? "\(Type)" : Type.name
}
```

Usage:

```
println(nameForClass(A.self)) // Prints "ClassA"
println(nameForClass(B.self)) // Prints "__lldb_expr_47.B"
```

An advantage of not using `AnyClass` is that you can also pass structs or enums and it'll work the same way:

```
struct C {}

enum D : Nameable {
    static var name: String {
        return "EnumD"
    }
}

println(nameForClass(C.self)) // Prints: "__lldb_expr_49.C"
println(nameForClass(D.self)) // Prints: "EnumD"
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know you could print Type that way!